# Flutter: what is the risk using global vairable?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

i'm working on flutter project and i need some variable that can be accessed to all file, im confused but currently this is how my code look like

this is my global.dart

```
String phone_num;
String token;
bool is_forget_pass;
```

and i access those variable like this:

```
import 'package:MY_PROJECT/View/Widgets/globals.dart' as globals;

globals.phone_num
```

what is the risk and cons using this method?

Comment: I think if the global variable is unique, you even don't need to use `as globals` because it will make you confused when you miss `as globals` somewhere else. Instead of that, you can create a static class `class Globals {static const String phone = 'phone';}` ([which is not recommended by Flutter](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_classes_with_only_static_members.html)) for easier to import to multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

This is what, I personally prefer for this kinda scenario

I define a class something like below example

```
class DataHolder{
    /// here I initialized variables to avoid null value
    static String phone_num = ';
    static String token = ';
    static bool is_forget_pass = false;
}
```

And now We can access those fields or variables from anywhere of our application by `DataHolder.token`